# react js warnings in console unknown prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toolbox

I've got a reactJS application with react-toolbox

in console I got this error:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `raised` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

Any Idea how I can solve this warning?
I don't want to remove the tag, is there workaround to get this worked with not removing this?

thanks

Update

```
 <Button icon='save' type="submit" label={<T value='processes.new.save'/>} raised primary/>
```

I use this stuff: http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/button

Comment: Could you post some or all of the code for your react component?

Comment: change `raised` to [`data-raised`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). You should avoid custom dom attributes which aren't in specification.

Comment: thats not working.

Comment: Added a code snipped above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the 'raised' prop is being added as a prop to the `<a>` that the `<Link>` makes. You can include additional information through the state property of the location.

check [Link docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#link)

Comment: thanks for the docs Link. But can you make an example for me?

Comment: thats not a solution for this problem

Comment: Are you getting any other warnings, like "Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead." @Felix

Comment: I've read this as well but the problems still pending ... and I think my one is another one

Answer (score 1):

React gives you a warning whenever you add attributes to a `DOM`-tag that is not in the HTML spec. `raised` is not a valid `<a />` attribute, so therefore React lets you know that you might have made a mistake. The tag - although it will be applied to the DOM (IIRC) - is not acted upon by any browser. If you need to add custom attributes for other reasons, use `data-`-prepended attributes, like `data-raised` in your case.

This looks like it needs to be a class or something instead of an attribute on the `a` tag - but without seeing your code, it's a bit hard to give a more precise answer.

Comment: thats not an solution. thats an attribute from react-toolbox so your solution does not work.

Comment: Looking at the code in react-toolbox, I think there is a different part of your code that triggers this warning. `<Button />` will only be an `<a />` tag if a `href` attribute is selected - which your example does not have. Please provide some more information / code samples for a more informed answer =)